# Dynamically Button Text?

Tags: android

Top rows of three buttons shows the top three values of the database but from the next rows again top three values were shown in the three buttons ?

```
public class ButtonTest extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

NoteHelper helper = null;
Cursor ourCursor = null;
NoteAdapter adapter = null;


    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    try {
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        helper = new NoteHelper(this);
        ourCursor = helper.getAll();

        startManagingCursor(ourCursor);

        adapter = new NoteAdapter(ourCursor);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("ERROR", "ERROR IN CODE :" + e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    helper.close();
}


class NoteAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    NoteAdapter(Cursor c) {
        super(ButtonTest.this, c);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View row, Context ctxt, Cursor c) {

        NoteHolder holder = (NoteHolder) row.getTag();
        holder.populateFrom(c, helper);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context ctxt, Cursor c, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
        NoteHolder holder = new NoteHolder(row);
        row.setTag(holder);
        return (row);
    }
}
```

My NoteHolder Class Is

```
static class NoteHolder {
    private Button b1 = null;
    private Button b2 = null;
    private Button b3 = null;



    NoteHolder(View row) {
        b1 = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.one);
        b2 = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.two);
        b3 = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.three);

    }

    void populateFrom(Cursor c, NoteHelper helper) {

        if (!c.moveToFirst()) return;
        b1.setText(helper.getNote(c));
        c.moveToNext();
        b2.setText(helper.getNote(c));
        c.moveToNext();
        b3.setText(helper.getNote(c));

    }
}
```

My SQLiteHelper Class is

```
class NoteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "note.db";
    private static final int SCHEMA_VERSION = 1;
    public SQLiteDatabase dbSqlite;

    public NoteHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, SCHEMA_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE Notes (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,note TEXT)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }


    public Cursor getAll() {
        return (getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT _id,note From Notes",
                null));

    }

    public String getNote(Cursor c) {           
        return(c.getString(1));
        }

    public Cursor getById(String id) {

        return (getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(
                "SELECT _id,note From Notes", null));
    }
}
```

}

My main.xml is

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:padding="6dip"
  android:background="#1F8B26">

<ListView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/list" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"></ListView>
```

Comment: Can't get you could you be more specific about your problem...

Comment: And i use the Table Layout to show the buttons

Comment: In row.xml i am using the table layout with three buttons in three column. set there text from the database my db has 16 values In the first row the buttons shows the top three values of the database but from the next row same three values were shown in the buttons

Comment: what is your exact problem here...

Comment: Lalit Poptani                                                          I am new in android and also in Stackoverflow and cant able to post the screen shot of the problem. Could you give me ur mail i will mail you the application

Comment: come to casual chat room, we can have a chat there....

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3960/discussion-between-puneet-joshi-and-lalit-poptani)

Comment: You are trying something that is not possbile, 1,2,3... upto 16 and you are generating 16 rows how can that be possible buddy....

Comment: The rows are depend upon the values in the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I want to say is that Gridview will be more suitable in your case
second you are getting multiple rows because cursor adapter will create those many view that it has rows and for each row you are again reading rows in `populateFrom() method` so that your rows are being repeated.

Instead of Cursor adapter use Base adapter

**Solution**

1) first create arraylist from your cursor

2) after getting arraylist create a object of NoteAdapter which is below

3) set adapter in gridview

```
private class NoteAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener {

ArrayList<Note> arrNote;
LayoutInflater inflater;
public NoteAdapter(ArrayList<Note> arr) {
    this.arrNote = arr;
    inflater = ExploreDestination.this.getLayoutInflater();
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return arrNote.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int index) {
    return arrNote.get(index);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int id) {
    return id;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup arg2) {
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.Notebutton, null);
    v.setTag(arrNote.get(position));
    ((Button)v).setText(arrNote.get(position).getTitle());
    v.setOnClickListener(this);
    return v;
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    //do your work 
}
}
```